# How to change vertex order to a polyline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vertices, sorting

I'm trying to change the vertex order of a polyline in QGIS.
I have an existing polyline that's closed (last vertex = first vertex).
The starting point of this polyline is in a totally casual position.

I'd like to change the vertex order for this polyline as follow:

- the first vertex must be in a position of my choiche;
- all other vertex must follow in the same order.

In the following example, I'd like to change the first vertex of this polyline from vertex 1 to vertex 43, then the other vertex must follow.
[image]

Comment: Do you want the vertex №43 to become the first, №44 to be the second, №45 to be the third and so on, and vertex №41 to become the №94 and №42 to become the last vertex №95 ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: try to digitize this polyline feature with tracing enabled and vertex snapping switched on. Begin digitizing from vertex №43 as you want. Then copy/paste attributes from already existing feature to the new one, if needed.

Comment: Yes, this would be the simplest solution, unfortunately it is not practicable because the number of these polylines is excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do this using Python**.

Assuming your line layer is named 'LineLyr', and you have an integer field called 'new_start' which represents the new starting vertex (8 in my example).

Execute this code in the QGIS Python console:

```
linelyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LineLyr')[0]

for old_line in linelyr.getFeatures():
    orig_vert = [v for v in old_line.geometry().vertices()]
    new_vert = orig_vert[old_line.attribute('new_start'):] + orig_vert[1:old_line.attribute('new_start')+1]
    new_line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(new_vert)
    linelyr.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({ old_line.id() : new_line })
```

**Original**

[image]

**Modified**

[image]

**Warning**
This script will modify your layer. I suggest you run on a duplicate layer to be sure it generates your desired output.

*Tested on QGIS v3.28*

Comment: Thank you, it works exactly as requested.